# import scss from create react library package

Tags: reactjs, package

I have created a npm package from create-react-library project.
I want to have a scss file in the package so i can import it in a different project( to be included in the .tgz file)
How a can edit this project config to include scss file?

Answer (score 0):

First, you must install sass with npm

```
npm install sass
```

Second, you can import your sass file to componenFile.js

```
import '../scss/FileName.scss';
```

Good luck

Comment: the file.sass is not included in the . tgz file. how it can be imported?